# Paperclip multiple file content types

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I want to be able to upload and validate a particular file type based on different views on the same model which is `UploadedFile`

This is what I have so far below and I want to be able to use `imageable` as polymorphic association with other models and validate depending on what controller is processing specific action. For example, I have form that submits images for a particular view then another one for submitting videos.

```
class UploadedFile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
    has_attached_file :assets

    validates_attachment :assets, 
        :content_type => /^image\/(png|gif|jpeg)/,
        :default_url => "/",
        :message => "only (png|gif|jpeg) images are allowed and the size cannot exceed 5mb"
        :size => { :in => 0..5000.kilobytes }


end
```

So what I need is if image is submitted, I validate according to image `validation_attachment` settings then change this to video settings if submitted from the video form.

How would I go about this with Paperclip and Rails 4?